# Можно ли подсветить слово в тексте в Angular?

Tags: typescript, angular

Есть поисковая форма,где по слову ищу все сходства в базе данных.В ангуляр вывожу списком.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос вот в чем,можно ли найденое совпадение подсветить для более удобной навигации, ведь текста может быть много и найти вхождение будет достаточно проблематично.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="text">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="search()">Submit</button>
```

```
<div *ngIf="SlidesFinded.length != 0">
<table class='table'>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Slide Id</th>
    <th> Presentation Id </th>
    <th>Slide Text</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let Slide of SlidesFinded;">
    <td>{{ Slide.idSlide }}</td>
    <td>NULL</td>
    <td> {{ Slide.textSlide }} </td>

  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Angular

```
export class TextSlidesComponent {  
public text: string;
public SlidesFinded: any [];

constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {}

search() {
this.http.get<string[]>('/search/' + this.text).subscribe(result => {
  this.SlidesFinded = result;
 },   error => { console.log('an error occured!'); console.log(error); });

}
}
```

Comment: [пример для первого ангуляра](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15519713/2881286) но суть должна быть понятна

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то вы плохо искали, в интернете уйма примеров на данную тематику, создаем `Pipe`, объявляем в `declarations` и используем в шаблоне:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'highlight'
})
export class HighlightPipe {
    public transform(value: string, predicate: string): string {
        return value.replace(new RegExp(predicate, 'gi'), `<mark>${predicate}</mark>`);
    }
}
```

В шаблоне связываем с директивой `innerHTML`:

```
<input #input (input)="search($event.target.value)">

<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor...>
        <td [innerHTML]="Slide.textSlide | highlight: input.value"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: я воспользовался примером,который мне указывали в коментариях. При использовании [innerHTML] у меня не отображает сайт.  Сделал в шаблоне так `<td>{{Slide.textSlide | highlight: text}}</td>` все работает,но найденый текст отображается с тегами,то есть не форматируется. Выходит,к примеру,так  _lorem <mark>example </mark> ipsum_

Comment: ну так потому что идет экранирование этих тегов и они вставляются как текст, что значит не отображает сайт?

Comment: так как я делаю Angular c .Net Cor'om у меня отображается страница с _Loading..._

Comment: причем тут .net, что консоль пишет?

Comment: недоглядел связь с inputom. Все работает,спасибо!